# Stroke on text in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows 8 metro Application and I want to add stroke to the text. I found out that there is no built-in function to do that. I tried to overlap two texts with different size but that was not giving the desired result. I want the result that the *Cut The Rope* is using. Here is a screenshot :

[image]

I want the effect where they have written total 36 as the number can vary.
I Unzipped there .xap file and checked there assets to see whether they are using image but there were no image.

I am stuck on this...  Please help, I want to achieve this in C#/XAML.

Answer (score 0):

On a quick search I didn't find anything relevant, but you could try something else :

Why not use a font which already has a stroke? You can use a lot of kind of fonts, as long as you add them to your project.

As you can read [here](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/embed-use-custom-font-in-windows-8-store-apps-win8dev-winrt/), it's quite easy.

Add your font file to your project and set the `Build Action` from Properties to `Content`. Then use it in `FontFamily` in `XAML` :

```
<TextBox Text="sampleText" FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/FontFileName.ttf#FontName" />
```

Comment: thanks for reply but I need some specific font with stroke otherwise i will have to create my own font which i dont want to do . i want to use BadaBoom BB and its not there with stroke